# BigQuery: Generating a new table from list of tables with different schemes

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with large denormalized genomic data from different sources.
The data is already uploaded to google bigQuery datasets and tables.
I would like to generate a new inclusive table that will include all the genomic samples in all the other tables with subset of the columns.
Each / some source table columns will be mapped to a different column names in the new inclusive table.
Is this possible? If yes, what would be the right (and cheap?) way to do so?

Many thanks,
  Eilalan

Comment: yes. it is possible. you just need to start writing some sql and when you get to the point where you have some issue  - you need to ask specific question so we will be able to help - Meantime, What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).